# disable dropdown when a textbox is not empty or has a value

Tags: javascript

I have the below code in javascript, here location id is a text box in my UI:

```
         var locationIdValue = $('[name="location_id"]').val();
         var chainIdSelection = $('[name="chain_id"]').val();
 if (chainIdSelection == "" && locationIdValue == "") {
    this.displayFailureMessage("Chain # is required.", 10000);
    canSearch = false;
 }
```

The Chain Id is a drop-down for which I have the below code:

```
<select class="${prefix}ChainIdSelect" name="chain_id">
    <option value=''><fmt:message key="select"/></option>
    <c:forEach var="chainId" items="${ chainDescriptionList }" >
        <option value="${chainId.chainId}"> ${chainId.chainId} - ${ chainId.description }</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

chain Id declaration is:

```
           {mData    :"chain_id"
            ,sTitle   :'<fmt:message key="location.summary.chain_id"/>' 
            ,sClass   :"chainId"
            ,bSortable:true
            ,"filter" :{selector:".${prefix}ChainIdSelect"}
            }
```

I am trying to disable chain id drop down when my location id text box has some value. I tried the below solution:

```
         if(locationIdValue != "" || locationIdValue != null){
            document.getElementByName("chainid").disabled = true; 
        }
```

This has not worked, and so have many other things which I have tried so far. Can anyone suggest a solution please.

Comment: When third statement is executed?

Comment: You have no element with the `id="chain_id"` in the code above

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly about your code but probably you want to implement disabling logic in event callback. I want to say add callback which will be triggered every time when `location_id` is changed.

In your case it would be something like this:

```
$('[name="location_id"]').change(function(){
    if(locationIdValue != "" || locationIdValue != null){
        $('[name="location_id"]').prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Please verify that callback is executed when value is changed!